# Is there a static analysis tool for identifying sql injection for php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection, static-analysis

Is there a static analysis tool for identifying sql injection for php/mysql.

A tool which run on a php script would analyze the sql statements and find if there are any possible sql injection possibilities for the sql statements.

Comment: Just be sure to escape the input, or you can check for certain keywords, but that could return false positives.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if a tool like that exists for PHP Script, but the security compass tools are great for a first analysis :

http://labs.securitycompass.com/index.php/exploit-me/

Answer (score 1):

What I found is rather disappointing.

[RATS](https://security.web.cern.ch/security/recommendations/en/codetools/rats.shtml) (branded as Fortify) has some PHP suport, but it doesn't detect SQL injections. Apparently [HP guys](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/software-solutions/software-security/index.html) are focused on .NET and Java apps.

[OWASP SWAAT Project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_SWAAT_Project) seems to be dead to me.

[RIPS Scanner](http://rips-scanner.sourceforge.net/) is a tool you can install on your web server and navigate in the source of your application on the web interface. Unfortunately it just hangs for me when I open it.

There is an online tool called [DevBug](http://devbug.co.uk/). It is not very useful to scan your entire codebase, but it's good for beginners to practice security.