# Editing php code with a program

Tags: php, python, programming-languages

So, here I am with 900+ pages of code, php code, each one a 1000+ lines long, no more than 20000... All vulnerable to sql injection. So rather than spend the better part of a year going in and incorporating mysql real escape string on every user input, I was planning on writing a program that would search lines of code and input it where ever it finds it needs it, for instance at every post variable. Any one deem this plausible? And if so what language would you recommend doing it in? I have a few ideas using php, but nothing solid. And I fear js would just be too slow.all help appreciated

Comment: Sounds better than being open to injection attacks and doing it by hand... even `sed` / `awk` etc... would probably do this

Comment: mysql_* functions are being deprecated so don't waste your time changing SQL injection vulnerable code to code that would just end up breaking in the future and may potentially be as unsafe. Spend the time to actually redo it using MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: can't advise you on this one, but just good luck to you man

Comment: Just noticed the deprecation, but its the same deal with mysqli

Comment: @cryptic, It is actually being deprecated in php 5.5 which I do believe is still in alpha.

Comment: @mjayt, which is stated to be released between Feb and March of 2013, so I don't understand your point since OP's code will be considered obsolete within a short time.

Comment: I'd look for a pre-existing tool first, and only fall back to writing one from scratch as a last resort. (And if you do, post it only and try to get others to use it and help find bugs.) [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072436/is-there-a-static-analysis-tool-for-identifying-sql-injection-for-php-mysql) seems to be asking for exactly such a tool, but there isn't a good answer there.

Comment: @nickbehrends where is MySQLi being deprecated? There are numerous functions deprecated in MySQLi and replaced with better equivalents if that is what you are talking about, but the extension is not, however the MySQL extension will be deprecated.

Comment: I was refering to the deprrcation of mysqlrealescspe, I will have to use mysqli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, there's already at least one [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072436/is-there-a-static-analysis-tool-for-identifying-sql-injection-for-php-mysql) asking for a static analysis tool to handle this. If there's an existing tool that's being used by multiple other projects, that usually makes it more trustworthy than something that hasn't been used by anyone.

Unfortunately, that question doesn't have any good answers. A quick search for PHP static analyzers turned up [PHP Source Code Security Framework](http://trac.assembla.com/php-ast) and [PHP_CodeSniffer](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer), but I know nothing about these beyond their names, so don't take that as an endorsement.

If you do have to build it yourself, your Python tag implies that you'd like to write it in Python. Normally, I'd say this is a great choice. But for something like this, getting buy-in from as many other people as possible is critical to being able to trust your code, and I think you might have more buy-in if you wrote it in, just because you can be sure that anyone who wants to use your tool will know PHP.

There is one alternative possibility: If your code follows a very consistent style, it might be possible to do something much simpler, that, despite not being generally applicable, does find all the SQL injection holes in your particular code. Since you're trying to write code that you can convince yourself is foolproof, the simplicity benefits might be worth it in this case.

Sorry this is all so vague, but it's a pretty vague question. All I can really say is that it's plausible in principle; I can't really guess whether it's feasible in practice.

Comment: I chose this as best answer simply because I foumd it the most inspiring, I will in fact write this program and I will post back on this when it is finished, also I will open source the code for others. Lastly I will try to code this in php and use python as a fall back

Answer (score 2):

I don't necessarily recommend this because you are essentially turning on magic quotes but if you don't have time to fix it properly then you could add this to a bootstrap file and include it in all of your scripts

```
foreach ($_POST as &$v) {
    $db->escape($v); // mysql_real_escape_string() or mysqli or pdo
}
unset($v);
```

You will need to modify this to check $v for arrays and escape those accordingly. You will also want to do the same for $_GET.

Be aware that while this may prevent the sql injection, it could cause other issues. I recommend getting some time to refactor.